# How to prevent access to session variables from within specific subfolder?

Tags: php, session

I have a website that resides in a subfolder of another website.  The two need to be completely separate, but as it stands the site in the sub folder can still access (and become confused by!) the session variables from the root site - is there a way I can prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use **different session()** variables... And make condition according to them...

Comment: When I start the session there are incomplete classes that belong to the parent site - obviously I don't want to include the parent site's classes when they are not being used - I'd much rather just separate the sessions.

Comment: What code you have tried and that's not working?